# Console Menu Generator in Python

Tags: python, menu, console, eval, generator

As the title says, I'm writing a Console Menu Generator in Python. I have 2 classes, Menu and Item. But I get into troubles. Here is the code:

```
class Menu:
    def AddItem(self,item):
        class Item:
            def __init__(self,text,ToDoNext):
                self.text=text
                ??????????????
        self.item.append(Item())
    def Show():
        for i in range(len(self.item)):
            print(str(i+1)+") "+str(self.item[i])+"\n")
        print("0) Back\n")
        option=int(input())
        self.item[option].????????????
```

This code basically do the next:

```
Main=Menu()
Menu.AddItem("Open file",ToDo1)
Menu.AddItem("Save file",ToDo2)
Menu.Show()

'''1) Open file
   2) Save file
   0) Back
   _
'''
```

If I write 1 and press enter should do the portion of code `ToDo1`, for example.
The solution that I thought is the nextone:

```
def ToDo1():
    print("Hello, world!")
Menu.AddItem("Say Hello","ToDo1()")
```

and use an `eval()` function inside the `Show()`.

But I'm not pretty sure this is not the correct way to do that.

I would like you to show me a better way, and if you have ever do something like that (Console Menu Generator) to share the code and see another way of doing the same.

Answer (score 7):

I absolutely recommend creating a class `Item`, even if you only have `text` and `function` attributes!
Who knows what kind of complex logic you will need later on.
With this in mind, creating a menu would probably look something like this:

```
main = Menu()
main.AddItem(Item("Open", openFile))
main.AddItem(Item("Close", closeFile))
```

Also, on top of your `text` and `function` attributes, you should add `parent` attribute to the `Item` class. `parent` simply points at the parent menu of our item:

```
main = Menu()

# automatically calls main.AddItem(item1)
open = Item("Open", openFile, main)

# automatically sets parent to main
main.Add(Item("Close", closeFile))
```

Now that we know how a proper `Menu` and `Item` should work, we can start coding the classes.

---

**Menu**

This shouldn't be too hard, all we need are `add_item()`, `remove_item()` and `draw()` methods and a list of `items`.
Also it would be good to draw our menu's name, so lets add `name` attribute.

```
class Menu:
    def __init__(self, name, items=None):
        self.name = name
        self.items = items or []

    def add_item(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)
        if item.parent != self:
            item.parent = self

    def remove_item(self, item):
        self.items.remove(item)
        if item.parent == self:
            item.parent = None

    def draw(self):
        print(self.label)
        for item in self.items:
            item.draw()
```

Obviously we could code much more methods and attributes for our menu, but that includes all the essential methods.

---

**Item**

Item class should be even easier, it hardly needs any methods at all.
Item obviously needs a `name` and a `function` (function will be ran when item gets activated), on top of that it has the earlier mentioned `parent` attribute.
We probably should create a setter for `parent`, which would automatically move the item under an other menu, but I'll leave that for you if you want to do it.
Also don't forget the `draw()`-method for item too, we must be able to draw our items the way they want to be drawn, not the way our `Menu` wants to draw them.

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, function, parent=None):
        self.name = name
        self.function = function
        self.parent = parent
        if parent:
            parent.add_item(self) # use add_item instead of append, since who
                                  # knows what kind of complex code you'll have
                                  # in add_item() later on.

    def draw(self):
        # might be more complex later, better use a method.
        print("    " + self.name)
```

---

**Final thoughts**

We've now finished our menu, it works and you should be able to use it as a basic menu.
However, the superior console menu would only have one class called `MenuItem`.
Each item's parent would be an other `MenuItem` (each, but the root `MenuItem`'s of course) and the menu would look something like this when it's drawn:

```
[-] Root
    [+] Submenu of Root
    [-] An other submenu of Root
          This menu runs functions, others open/close
         <This menu has focus on it>
          Select this menu by pressing mousedown
    [+] A third submenu of Root
```

Where not giving `function` parameter would create `items` list and allow users to close/open the menuitem.
If `function` is given, it will work normally and only execute the function when selected.
To go even a step further, we would have separated `MenuItem` and two subclasses: `ActionMenu` and `ContainerMenu`.
But please keep in mind, this is somewhat hard to code and not for beginners. You might wanna stick with the first version I went through.

Comment: Someone has really spent some time working on menus? This gave ME alot of new information, totally got my upvote!

Answer (score 0):

Functions can be passed around freely in Python.  If you say `AddItem("Say Hello", ToDo1)`, you pass the value `ToDo1`, which is a function object.  You can then store it in `self.function`, later fish it with `fn = self.item[option].function`, and then call it with `fn()`.  It's all clearer when you realize that a regular function call like `do_stuff()` is actually two things: first getting the function object from the variable `do_stuff` (which is typically a never-modified global variable), then calling this function object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example

usually the Class Menu part would be in another file called "myMenu" and imported with the command `from myMenu import myMenu`

items is an array of dictionaries.  Each list item has a dictionary with two entries, "text" and "func"

The input is called as n-1 as arrays start at zero

```
import sys
class myMenu:
    items=[]

    def AddItem(self,text,function):
        self.items.append({'text': text, 'func':function})

    def Show(self):
        c=1
        for l in self.items:
            print c, l['text'],"\n"
            c = c +1

    def Do(self,n):
        self.items[n]['func']()

def clist():
    print "cheeses are wensleydale and cheddar\n"

def bye():
    print "bye"
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m=myMenu()
    m.AddItem("cheese",clist)
    m.AddItem("quit",bye)

while(True):
    m.Show()
    n=input("choice>")
    m.Do(n-1)
```

If you want to have the menu items as a class instead of a dictionary, then declare the class immediately after class MyMenu, so something like this (not tested)

```
class myMenu:
    items=[]
    class Item:
        func=None
        text="default"

        def __init__(self,t,f):
            self.text=t
            self.func=f

    def AddItem(self,text,function):
        self.items.append(Item(text,function))
```

Answer (score 0):

for future readers! it's easy to have a python console menu using `console-menu`.

```
pip install console-menu
```

now, let's implement our menu

```
from consolemenu import *
from consolemenu.items import *

# Create the menu
menu = ConsoleMenu("Title", "Subtitle")

# Create some items

# MenuItem is the base class for all items, it doesn't do anything when selected
menu_item = MenuItem("Menu Item")

# A FunctionItem runs a Python function when selected
function_item = FunctionItem(
    "Call a Python function", input, ["Enter an input"]
)

# A CommandItem runs a console command
command_item = CommandItem("Run a console command", "touch hello.txt")

# A SelectionMenu constructs a menu from a list of strings
selection_menu = SelectionMenu(["item1", "item2", "item3"])

# A SubmenuItem lets you add a menu (the selection_menu above, for example)
# as a submenu of another menu
submenu_item = SubmenuItem("Submenu item", selection_menu, menu)

# Once we're done creating them, we just add the items to the menu
menu.append_item(menu_item)
menu.append_item(function_item)
menu.append_item(command_item)
menu.append_item(submenu_item)
menu.show()
```

you would get a menu like this
[image]