# How to create a menu or directory?

Tags: python, menu, directory

How do I make a simple Menu/Directory using Python? I would like to have letters that the user would press to do tasks, and when they enter the letter after the prompt, the task is done... for example:

A. Create Username 
B. Edit Username 
C. Exit

Choice:

And then all the user has to do is enter one of the letters after the prompt.

Comment: I think you'll find that people are more then willing to help posters, (even sometimes provide code samples) if some effort has been made on the posters behalf.  What have you tried? What specifically are you having difficulty with?

Comment: @dm03514 I've looked around at all the different codes, but none of it really made sense to me. I just started learning Python four or five days ago, and most of the terms and language are still very foreign to me. I'll post a more concise question next time!

Comment: for a more interactive menu, use the module `curses`

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [curses](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html) library? It's a lot of overhead, but if this application becomes cumbersome, this library can really simplify some of the more common actions for terminal apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (very) basic approach would be something like this:

```
print "A. Create Username"
print "B. Edit Username"
input = raw_input("Enter your choice")

if input == "A":
    print "A was given" 
if input == "B":
    print "B was given"
```

Answer (score 1):

A very basic version:

```
def foo():
    print "Creating username..."

def bar():
    print "Editing username..."

while True:
    print "A. Create Username"
    print "B. Edit Username"
    print "C. Exit"
    choice = raw_input()
    if choice.lower() == 'a':
       foo()
    elif choice.lower() == 'b':
       bar()
    elif choice.lower() == 'c':
       break
    else:
       print "Invalid choice"
```

Accepts upper- and lower-case letters as choice.

Answer (score 0):

[Console Menu Generator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083900/console-menu-generator-in-python)

Have a read and post back with your efforts as stated by dm03514

Comment: Tip to OP: if you do follow this example/answer, please consider using [proper capitalization](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names).