# Python console menu using a dictionary

Tags: python, windows, menu, console

I'm building a Windows application using Python 2.7 that requires a simple console menu, ex:

1. Do something
2. Do something else
3. Exit

There will be several menus, the main menu will link to others. So I am attempting to avoid the scenario of having a bunch of stacks of `if input == "1"` code. Similar to this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454882/how-to-create-a-menu-or-directory/17455013#) link. My below code is currently skipping the main menu and executing every option in my second menu. I've looked it over but I'm failing to see the logic in why it is performing the way it does.

```
computer = ""

# need a class for each of the options in power_menu
class power:
    def logoff(self, computer):
        print "logging off " + computer

    def restart(self, computer):
        print "restarting " + computer

    def shutdown(self, computer):
        print "shutting down " + computer

def set_computer():
    global computer
    #os.system("cls")
    # optionally print the banner
    computer = raw_input("Computer: ")
    # check the computer is online

    # move to the main menu with the computer parameter
    menu().menu_main(computer)

def func_quit():
    sys.exit()

def invalid(computer):
    #os.system("cls")
    print "INVALID CHOICE!"
    menu().menu_main(computer)

class menu():
    def menu_main(self, computer):
        opts_main = {"1":("Power Options", self.menu_power(computer)),
            "2":("Service Options", self.menu_service(computer)),
            "3":("Service Tag & Warranty", self.menu_warranty(computer)),
            "4":("User Options", self.menu_user(computer)),
            "5":("Change Computer", set_computer),
            "6":("Quit hd-con", func_quit)
            }
        for key in sorted(opts_main.keys()):
            print "\t" + key + ":  " + opts_main[key][0]
        ans = raw_input("Selection: ")
        try:
            opts_main.get(ans, [None, invalid])[1]()
        except Exception, e:
            print e
        #men_sel()

    def menu_power(self, computer):
        opts_power = {"1":("Logoff", power().logoff(computer)),
            "2":("Restart", power().restart(computer)),
            "3":("Shutdown", power().shutdown(computer)),
            "4":("Main Menu", menu.menu_main),
            "5":("Quit hd-con", func_quit)
            }
        for key2 in sorted(opts_power.keys()):
            print "\t" + key2+":  " + opts_power[key2][0]
        ans2 = raw_input("Selection: ")
        try:
            opts_power.get(ans2)[1]()
            #pow_sel()
        except:
            raise
```

My output for the above is looking like this.

```
Computer: asdf
logging off asdf
restarting asdf
shutting down asdf
        1:  Logoff
        2:  Restart
        3:  Shutdown
        4:  Main Menu
        5:  Quit 
Selection:
```

I'm looking for guidance on using a dictionary for use in a console menu, fixes for the existing code, or a recommended direction to take this instead of what i'm looking at.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assignment to the dictionary:

```
opts_main = {"1":("Power Options", self.menu_power(computer)), ...}
```

is *calling* `menu_power`, and storing the *return value* (`None`) in the tuple. You can use e.g. [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to avoid this:

```
from functools import partial 

opts_main = {"1":("Power Options", partial(self.menu_power, computer)), ...}
```

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly once I figured out what partial expects and how to pass functions and values to it. Another awesome built-in feature of Python I didn't know about. I appreciate your quick response and detailed sample usage.